# Rails routing alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm using Rails 2.3.16 and Ruby 1.8.7

I have the next routing:

```
map.namespace :controller1 do |c1|
    c1.resources :controller2, :member => { :action1 => :get, :action2 => :get }
end
```

Now, I access with the url:

```
domain/controller1/controller2/action1/:id
```

I need acces action1 with url `domain/:id`

I tried many ways but I can't.

How can I do this with the rails routing?

Can I get the action1 with the two ways?

Comment: *I tried many ways but I can't.* Can you show a couple of what you thought were the most promising approaches you took but failed?

Comment: I used the way ":as", I think is ok. I think that I did wrong the implementation.

Comment: I was looking for something more specific and complete. Show examples of what you tried.

Comment: I read  the rails guide 2.3 "http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html". I tried to many many ways.